# Android 10 how to check if an uri thats pointing to an image exists

Tags: image, kotlin, uri, android-10.0

In my app I'm displaying images that I get from the uri provided by the onActivityResult method.
I want to check if the images that the uris are pointing to still exists before displaying them, but I don't know how to do that.

An example uri looks like this:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A78989
```

From other answers on SO, I figured I need to use contentResolver somehow, but I don't know how to properly do that.

Comment: Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. If it succeeds, the `Uri` is still valid, and you can just close the resulting stream. If it throws an exception, the `Uri` is no longer valid, either because the content is no longer there or you no longer have rights to it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the help!